# How to deal with multiple lambda in a question?

Tags: python, lambda, arguments

```
def f1(x,y,z):
   return x(y,z)
def f2(x,y):
   return y(x)
print(f1(lambda x,y: x+1, 2, lambda x: x**2))
```

I am very confused on how to tackle multiple lambdas in a questions

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches to implement lambda functions can be like this:

```
# f1 function 
'''
def f1(x, y, z):
    return x * y * z
'''
# Writing f1 function in terms of lambda
f1 = lambda x, y, z: x * y * z

'''
def f2(x, y):
    return x * y
'''
# Writing f2 function in terms of lambda
f2 = lambda x, y: x * y

result_1 = f1(3, 5, 7)  # passing x = 3, y = 5, and z = 7 in lambda function 1
result_2 = f2(3, 5)     # passing x = 3 and y = 5 in lambda function 2

print(result_1)             # This will print 105
print(result_2)             # This will print 15
print(result_1 + result_2)  # This will print 120
```